# How to find li and inject ul before each set of li in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an indexed array of html tags, each index contain html opening and closing tag an it's value in it. I want to modify some of them, for example I want li tags to get wrapped with ul, around them. But with the same array order.

```
Array
(
[0] => <li>some text</li>
[1] => <pre>text area data</pre>
[2] => <li>some value</li>
)
```

this is how I want it to be

```
 Array
(
[0] => <ul>
[1] => <li>some text</li>
[2] => </ul>
[3] => <pre>text area data</pre>
[4] => <ul>
[5] => <li>some value</li>
[6] => </ul>
)

    $arr2 = [];
    $a=0;

    foreach($arr1 as $k => $v)
    {
        if($a == 0)
        $arr2[] = '<ul>';
        $a=1;
        
       if(strpos($v, '<li>') !== false){
        $arr2[] = $v;
    }
```

Comment: In your `foreach` could you not just use your second if? If it's not false, then `$arr2[] = '<ul>'; $arr2[]=$v; $arr2[] = '</ul>'`, else `$arr2[] = $v`.

Comment: if I do that it close </ul> after every other element

Comment: like <ul><li></li></ul><pre></pre></ul>

Comment: For example https://3v4l.org/4JXNr

Comment: this way it adds ul after each li, but I need it after each set of lis

Comment: Then you'll probably need to have a flag that notes whether a list is open. If you've not opened a list (e.g. `$openList = false`), and the text has an `<li>`, add `<ul>`, add the string and set the flag to true (`$openList = true;`). If the flag is true and the string contains an li, add the string value, if the flag is true but there is no li, add the </ul> and set the flag back to false before adding the current string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code tracks if your currently in a list or not, then for each item it checks if it starts with `<li>` and the state.

If it is a `<li>` on not in a list, then it adds the `<ul>` first and sets the state, if it's not a `<li>` an it is in a list then it adds the `</ul>`.

To ensure it closes any list, after the loop if it is in a list, then it closes the tag...

```
$arr2 = [];
$inList = false;
foreach($arr1 as $index => $value)
{
    if ( substr(trim($value), 0, 4) == "<li>" ) {
        if ( ! $inList )    {
            $arr2[] = '<ul>';
            $inList = true;
        }
    }
    else    {
        if ( $inList )  {
            $arr2[] = '</ul>';
            $inList = false;
        }
    }
    $arr2[] = $value;
}
if ( $inList )  {
    $arr2[] = '</ul>';
    $inList = false;
}
```